# How to display filtered items of an interface?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have an interface `Med` that has a few properties such as the drugClass, dosage, and name. I then create an array using the interface and declared a bunch of drugs. How would I filter it by drugClass and then display it to the page?

```
// in Medications.ts
export interface Med {
  dosage: number;
  name: string;
  drugClass: medForm;
  forDog: boolean;
  forCat: boolean;
}

export const medications: Med[] = [
  {
    dosage: 0.03,
    name: "Meloxicam",
    drugClass: "Oral",
    forDog: true,
    forCat: true,
  }, ....// more here

// in page.tsx
import { Med, medications } from "./Medications"; 

export default function Home() {
 const filteredOralData = medications.filter(
    (med) => med.drugClass === "Oral"
  );

return (
<div>
<ul className="list-group">
                {filteredOralData.map((item) => (
                  <li>{item //ERROR: Type 'Med' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1450, 9): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<LiHTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement>, HTMLLIElement>'}</li>
                ))}
              </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem (explained)

The error you're encountering is because you are trying to render the entire item object directly within the `<li>` element, and React expects a valid ReactNode which an object is not, so we must extract it from the object.

### Solution

To do this, we need to specify which property of the item you want to display. For example, you can display the name property. Here's the modified code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Med, medications } from './Medications';

export default function Home() {
  const filteredOralData = medications.filter((med) => med.drugClass === 'Oral');

  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="list-group">
        {filteredOralData.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{item.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Changes made:

1. Added import React from 'react'; to import the React library.
2. Added `key={index}` to each `<li>` element to provide a unique identifier for each item in the list (React requires this for efficient rendering and will throw warnings and/or errors if not satisfied).
3. Changed `{item}` to `{item.name}` to display the drug name within the `<li>` element.

Comment: Yeah, if you check my solution that I posted that's basically how I figured it out. Still awesome explanation though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked!

```html
<ul className="list-group">
  {filteredOralData.map((item) => (
    <li key={item.name}>
      {/* Render desired properties here */}
      Name: {item.name} | Dosage: {item.dosage} | Drug Class: {item.drugClass}
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).